# return difference between now and a given date with conditions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying a very simple idea but hard to implement one.

I want to return the difference between two given dates and times in seconds. Note I want to get the same result in these conditions:

- No matter if we test it in Chrome or Firefox. it should return the same result in both.
- No matter if the end-user sets the Time Zone in his/her system in different time zones.

So I tried this:

```js
// input your custom Date below
const date = new Date('2020-6-24 14:22:00'); // Set End Time 
const dif = (date.getTime() / 1000) - ((new Date().getTime())/1000);
console.log(dif);
```

if you check this with **different browsers** with **different timezones** set in your system you will get different results!

I want all users (Those who set the timezone to Havana and Those who set the time zone to Tehran on their systems) see the same result.

The same result is the only thing I can think of right now.

The wired and confusing thing here is that if I log this simple log, I have different results in Firefox and Chrome:

```
console.log(new Date());
```

Note: I set my system's timezone to Havana.

Answer (score 1):

There can definitely be many issues with handling dates and times, including time zones, leap years, leap seconds, and daylight savings time.

However that doesn't seem to be what's happening here. Remember that internally JavaScript Date objects use universal time (UTC), so once you have the time stored correctly, comparisons should work regardless of the time zones.

I used this function:

```
const dateDiffSeconds = function(date1, date2) {
  return Math.round(Math.abs(date1.getTime()-date2.getTime())/1000);
}
```

Note that I'm using `Math.round()` to round up as well as `Math.abs` so it doesn't matter which date is larger. Notably, you can even subtract dates directly without `getTime()`.

When I ran it in Firefox, Chrome and Node using various tests I got consistent results, including when I changed time zones.

One test to run is this: instead of using the current time, compare two preselected constant dates.

I suspect you're having trouble with one or both of these things:

1. **Time zone representation: Specify the date in UTC time.** If you want a user in Tehran to see the same time difference as in Havana, you have to make sure you send them both the same date. If the date is sent without the time zone specified, both clients will convert the date into local time, which means they'll be separated by time zones. Instead, send the dates in UTC time.
2. **Browser synchronization:** It's possible also that when you're testing the results in two different browsers, you're not keeping them synchronized tightly enough. When I tested it, I used `setInterval()` with a low timeout setting (much lower than a second) to keep comparing the current time with the test date. If you're just refreshing the browsers manually the times likely won't be the same.

Comment: Ok... Thanks for the great answer. plus one for now...  I'll test this ...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to use `Date.now()` instead of `new Date()`. This returns a number of milliseconds that you can easily subtract.

Just don't forget that time measurement on computers is weird. You can end up with `end - start < 0` for a variety of reasons.